# Differenze di uso tra "verso", "nei riguardi di" e "nei confronti di"

Tags: word-usage, difference, prepositions

Mi piacerebbe sapere se ci sono differenze di uso tra "verso", nel senso figurato che viene spiegato [qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/verso2/), e le espressioni "nei riguardi di" e "nei confronti di". Per esempio, sono corrette tutte queste frasi?

> - Molti studenti hanno sentimenti negativi *verso* la matematica.
> - Molti studenti hanno sentimenti negativi *nei riguardi della*  matematica.
> - Molti studenti hanno sentimenti negativi *nei confronti della*  matematica.

Comment: A me suona strana la frase, avere sentimenti negativi riferendosi alla matematica. "Molti italiani hanno sentimenti negativi verso/nei riguardi/nei confronti dei politi" potrebbe essere una valida alternativa.

Comment: @Josh61: Purtroppo molti dei miei studenti mostrano tali sentimenti, ma non so se questa idea si possa esprimere in modo migliore.

Comment: Confermo l'impressione di Charo, e aggiungo che è un luogo comune arrivare quasi a vantarsi di non capire niente di matematica.

Comment: verso e contro sono probabilmente le locuzioni più usate

Comment: @DaG Dillo a me! Uno dei miei obiettivi nel corso di “Didattica della matematica” che tengo è di insegnare come non avere questa attitudine verso la materia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Nei riguardi di](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5206/differenze-di-uso-tra-verso-nei-riguardi-di-e-nei-confronti-di): (Treccanionline)

> - Perifr. prep.: nei riguardi di [per introdurre cose o persone su cui si esprime un giudizio o si precisa qualcosa: sono sempre stato critico nei suoi r.; sono stati presi severi provvedimenti nei r. dei funzionari colpevoli] ≈ **nei confronti di, verso**.

Le tre espressioni sono sostanzialmente sinonimi e quindi sono intercambiabili.

Answer (score 2):

La prima e terza frase sono corrette. Per quanto riguarda la seconda, l'espressione più usata è "riguardo a":

> Molti studenti hanno sentimenti negativi riguardo alla matematica.

e comunque sarebbe, secondo me, la meno comune delle tre.

Naturalmente "verso" ha anche altri significati, non sostituibili con "nei confronti di" o "riguardo a" (eg vado verso il mare etc.), un po' come accade con "envers" in catalano.